# How to treat same ALIKE enteries in database as one in Group By

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to wite a Mysql query to group all the same entries in database as one.I have a data base with different colors name , entries in database are like

```
Contract        Color

OG-46374    I.Khaki
OG-46375    I-KHAKI
OG-46376    I KHAKI
OG-46377    W Ocher
OG-46378    W.Ocher
```

Now the problem is my database in treating all these values as different entries whereas i cant handle or force the operator to write the exact values how can I treat  all "I Khaki" and W ocher color as one not different colors in group by clause 
My Sql query is somehow like

```
SELECT 
    *,
    ROUND(SUM(meter_yard_length), 0) AS TotaL_Length_Contract,
    ROUND(SUM(IF(quality = 'A', meter_yard_length, 0)),
            0) AS A_Quality_length,
    ROUND(SUM(IF(quality = 'B', meter_yard_length, 0)),
            0) AS B_Quality_length GROUP BY r.contract_no, r.color DESC;
```

Kindly tell the generic solution because i have many possibilities like "I*khaki" "I--Khaki" etc i cant control all of them through replace etc

Comment: There's not going to be a "generic" solution that fixes all your bad data. Fix your system so that it only accepts proper values, preferably a color table with the name, and then store color id to your table.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the very limited sample data you provided.  I see two problems with color names.  First, not all letters are in the same case always.  And second, there maybe be, in a given position, either a space, period, or dash, when in fact all three represent the same logical name.  We can try using `REPLACE` to convert the dots and dashes into space, then use `LOWER()` to handle the case issue.

```
SELECT 
    contract_no,
    LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(color, '.', ' '), '-', ' '))
    ROUND(SUM(meter_yard_length), 0) AS TotaL_Length_Contract,
    ROUND(SUM(IF(quality = 'A', meter_yard_length, 0)),
        0) AS A_Quality_length,
    ROUND(SUM(IF(quality = 'B', meter_yard_length, 0)),
        0) AS B_Quality_length
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    contract_no,
    LOWER(REPLACE(REPLACE(color, '.', ' '), '-', ' '));
```

### Demo

Comment: I am asking for the generic solution and yes its the limited data because i cant post all my database here there can be a '.' or '-' or a space or anyother possibilty what can i do if i have the color name which neither have a . or - but is in lowercase and has a '*' between it than? soo kindly tell the generic solution like if i use khaki with INSTR it shows me all colors having khaki color but the problem is i cant hardcode the khaki color only so not using INSTR for that reason

Comment: Nope.  I'm not going to dance based on your lengthy comment.  If you have other edge cases in your data, then it is _your_ responsibility to phrase your question appropriately.  This is one correct answer based on what you actually did ask.

Comment: hahah ok my bad but whatever i post you will simple replace it with "REPLACE" clause and magic will happen